# Should I expect my nginx cache directory to fill up right away?

Tags: nginx, caching

I added a cache to my Nginx reverse proxy, so it could cache all the API responses. But after restarting my Nginx server and confirmed that there are no errors in my configuration file, my cache directory is still empty, and I'm not noticing any performance improvements.

Am I expecting something that is not supposed to happen right away, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my configuration file. it's stored in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.example.com.conf` and I made sure to symlink it inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=api_cache:10m max_size=30g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 10G;

    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    proxy_connect_timeout 86400;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400;

    location / {
        proxy_cache api_cache;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4040;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm your directory has the write permission also please make sure that the port is not already occupied by any other service.

Comment: The directory was created by nginx @Rounak-Cod so it already have the necessary rights.